# Bitmap.GetHbitmap() fails on XP

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0

My NET 2.0 Winforms app works beautifully on Vista and Windows 7 but a call to `Bitmap.GetHbitmap()` returns `null` on Windows XP (even with SP3). The underlying `Bitmap` is a PNG and is loaded from resources. It is loaded correctly so it is down to `GetHbitmap()`. I have tried calling both overloads with the same result.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're not getting `null` but `IntPtr.Zero` instead, right?

Comment: Try updating the relevant DLL: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=6A63AB9C-DF12-4D41-933C-BE590FEAA05A&displaylang=en

Comment: Oops. Sorry. That is correct. Not `null` but `IntPtr.Zero`.

Comment: Could you post some code? I just tried on XP SP3 and I get a valid HBITMAP...

Comment: Hm... I must have forgotten my medication. I can't reproduce this anymore no matter how hard I try. I do have another issue though which deserves a separate question. Thanks for everybody's help.

Comment: can you close this question if it's no longer relevant?

Comment: Sure, but none of the reasons offered for closing reflect my closing intention.

Comment: @wpfwannabe: ... and yet, it remains in the "unanswered questions" queue.

Comment: @MarcL. I just voted. It needs more votes to be closed. I can't seem to just close it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Watch out for memory leaks while debugging and working with `.GetHBitmap`

When you're using this function you need to delete the object manually!!

MSDN example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dz311e4.aspx

```
<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("gdi32.dll")> _
    Private Shared Function DeleteObject (ByVal hObject As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function



    Private Sub DemonstrateGetHbitmap()
        Dim bm As New Bitmap("Picture.jpg")
        Dim hBitmap As IntPtr
        hBitmap = bm.GetHbitmap()

        ' Do something with hBitmap.
        DeleteObject(hBitmap)
    End Sub
```

and similar question: 
[Image loading memory leak with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714841/image-loading-memory-leak-with-c-sharp)

Regards