# Releasing Memory from unused Bitmapsources

Tags: wpf, vb.net, image-processing, memory-leaks

I try to load large image from a .RAW file into a System.Windows.Controls.Image by this code:

```
Dim pf As PixelFormat = PixelFormats.Gray16
Dim rawStride As Integer = Convert.ToInt32((Convert.ToInt32(RAWImage.ImageSize.Width) * pf.BitsPerPixel + 7) \ 8)
bitmap = BitmapSource.Create(Convert.ToInt32(RAWImage.ImageSize.Width), Convert.ToInt32(RAWImage.ImageSize.Width), 96, 96, _
                                                         pf, Nothing, ImagePixelvalues, rawStride)
MainPictureBox.Source = bitmap
```

where ImagePixelvalues is uint16().
My problem is about memory leakage caused by `bitmapsource`. if I load for example 100 times RAW image in the Image Control, Windows Task Manager Performance shows that the Physical memory of the system increasing an after a while. This means that previous `bitmapsource`are not released and `GC` cannot collect them. Please let me know your idea about this How can i release `bitmapsource`?

Comment: How do you know that BitmapSource is responsible for increasing memory consumption? It could as well be your ImagePixelvalues. You should consider using a memory profiler.

Comment: How are you releasing the image? Are you trying to force GC, or did you try any trick (ex: setprocessworkingsetsize)?

Comment: @Clemens: I null the ImagePixelValue but the problem still remain.

Comment: @Caveman: I used GC.Collection() but there is no thing happened I do not any thing about setprocessworkingsetsize!!!

Comment: There are similar problems here but no one can solved it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714841/image-loading-memory-leak-with-c-sharp?rq=1
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684489/how-do-you-make-sure-wpf-releases-large-bitmapsource-from-memory?rq=1
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428146/memory-leak-while-asynchronously-loading-bitmapsource-images?rq=1

Comment: @Clemens,Caveman: I build up another test. I assign a window with this Image as child to a parent window, When I close child physical memory does not released this test may be describe the problem more !!

Answer (score 0):

When you're done using each bitmap, you could try

```
   bitmap.Dispose
```

Comment: Dear David Bitmap Class has no Dispose method and this is my problem I cannot dispose bitmap :D

Comment: I meant the bitmap  variable  you defined

Comment: I use bitmapsource of WPF, I confused about your solution I do not define a new bitmap class

Comment: This line..  MainPictureBox.Source = bitmap..  Bitmap is a variable isn't it?

Comment: yes sure:
`Dim bitmap As BitmapSource = BitmapSource.Create(Convert.ToInt32(ImageSize.Width), Convert.ToInt32(ImageSize.Height), 96, 96, _
                                    pf, Nothing, PixelValues, rawStride)`

Comment: you should be able to dispose that then after setting it to nothing - Something else I read about by the way was to turn off bitmap image caching - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapcacheoption(v=vs.110).aspx - though I don't know if this also affects bitmapsource.. I see nobody else has been able to answer your question yet either :-/